# Is there a way to set custom pluralizations in EDM designer 2010?

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2010, pluralize

I am using VS 2010 and I have an entity 'Person'.

The pluralization-service turns its plural to 'People', I want it to be Persons.
Is there a place where I can manage the pluralizations library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Not in Visual Studio](http://blogs.msdn.com/adonet/archive/2009/05/20/sneak-preview-pluralization-in-entity-framework-4-0.aspx), no.

> In the meantime though you can drop down to the API level and create your own implementation derived from the abstract PluralizationService class. Once you’ve done this you can tell the EntityModelSchemaGenerator to use your implementation, rather than the default, to produce a model using your particular pluralization rules. This is an API only solution, we don’t yet provide a way to choose a different pluralizer in Visual Studio.

You can use the pluralization service in your own code, however, and customize it there.

[Here's an example](http://www.danrigsby.com/blog/index.php/2009/05/19/entity-framework-40-pluralization/).

Comment: I looked at the linked example, and I am confused as to when and where you would call the line

: var edm = generator.GenerateMetadata();