# EF singularizes "Changes" to "Chanx"

Tags: entity-framework

I have a Table in my data model which is called **ContractProductChanges**. In the EF data model wizard, I chose to pluralize or singularize object names. After finishing the wizard it names the entity **ContractProductChanx**. But **ContractProductChange** makes more sense imho, so I have to change that manually.

I'm in early development phase, consequently I update the .edmx file a lot. Is there a way to override the singularization rules?

Comment: +1 good question. I have exactly same problem.

Comment: It will only pluralize or singularize new items it's adding, though - once you've manually corrected it once you shouldn't have to change it again?

Comment: I always delete all entities from the .edmx before updating it from the database. I know that I don't have to do that each time, but it feels cleaner.

Comment: Check out this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2696825/is-there-a-way-to-set-custom-pluralizations-in-edm-designer-2010 seems like its a bit hairy to chanx the rules yourself but it may be worthwhile for something you encounter often.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is old, but I'm still finding this now. The only reason I could possibly think of is the word "Phalanx" which becomes plural as "Phalanages". I can't think of any other words that are like this, so it defaults to a very odd default.

Note that is does this with any word that ends with `anges`, `inges` or `ynges` including ranges, charges, hinges, or many other words.

I have [logged an issue](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/2106) in entity framework as I think this behaviour is very odd, and causes quite a bit of confusion (even if it is easy to fix).

Comment: your guess is correct!  the EF team responded to your query and explained that they cannot change the regretable rule that changes  plural "..ges" into singular "..x" until next major revision of EF

Comment: This still happens