# How fix the name for class not auto singularize

Tags: c#, postgresql, visual-studio, entity-framework, class

Using EF to create the classes I choose the singularize option. Some of the classes were singularize but other doesn't.

This work ok:

```
products -> product
presentations -> presentation
```

But this two wasn't:

```
price_sources -x-> price_source
user_types -x-> user_type
```

[image: enter code here]

- How can I fix the names of the classes weren't singularized?
- How can I fix the names of the classes with underscore?
- How make sure next update from db does not break the names again?

Comment: Just rename them yourself in a model. Update will not break them if you rename. You can even rename all columns to follow c# conventions (PriceSourceID and so on).

Comment: @Evk What you mean "rename them in a model"? those files are autogenerated and update will lose any changes

Comment: I guess this is database first rather than code first.

Comment: @phuzi You are correct.The db is already created

Comment: I mean in model designer like on your screenshot. Open edmx file in designer by double-clicking and rename there. This file is not autogenerated. Not sure what else to say here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Manual method:**

Right click on empty space in the edmx window and select `Model Browser`.

In the `Model Browser` of the edmx file you can rename the generated class names for the Tables under the `DBModel --> Entity Types` by right clicking on the class names and selecting `Rename`. This will not break the code on subsequent updating of the models from database. But if you delete and re-add the same table you will have to repeat the above steps.

I do these steps to avoid the CA warning for using underscores in class / property names

Comment: I dont have Entity Types, I have dbModel.tt and under the class "right click" doesn't have the option to rename   https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBfZA.png

Comment: I meant in the Model Browser not solution explorer.. Updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that tables with underscores cannot be automatically pluaralized/singularized in EM.

For more details, see:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/efdesign/2008/12/01/pluralization/

You will have to configure the table name explicitly.

You can also use a custom pluralization service to write your own rules.

Details here: [Entity Framework EDMX - Entity Pluralization Fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11090639/entity-framework-edmx-entity-pluralization-fix)

Comment: how you configure the name explicitly? And will have to do it each time update the model from db?

Comment: Oops, look again.